# NullPointerException when removing head node

Tags: java, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
 public void remove(E del) { //this deletes head node
    if (size == 0) {

    }
    else {
        Node<E> temp = head; //start at head
        head = head.next; //head points to head.next
        temp = head.next; //move to the next node after head
        temp.prev = null; //set prev equal to null
        head.next = null; //setting head's next equal to null to make empty

    }
}



public String toString() {
        Node<E> temp = head; //temp node starting at head to walk the list

        if (temp == null) return ""; //if there is nothing to start at return nothing

        String output = "[ ";

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //cycle through while i < size

            if(i == 0) { //if is index 0, then grab the data of head
                output += temp.data;
            }
            else { //else if i is more than 0, then grab the data of head and display with output
                output += ", \n" + temp.data;
            }
            temp = temp.next; // sets the temporary head equal to temp.next;
        }
        output += " ]";
        return output;
    }
```

I am trying to create a `remove()` method that will remove the head node of the double linked list. I have tried many different ways to make this method work but every time I run the program, I am always method with `"NullPointerException: Cannot read field "data" because "temp" is null"` and I am not sure why I keep getting this error. When I read the error it always points back to line 191 which happens to be in the `toString()` method.

To remove the head node I figured that I would have to create a temp node that starts at the head node. After starting at the head node, I would use `head = head.next` to point to the next of head and then I would set that to `head.next = null` so it would severe the connection between the head and the node after it.

Comment: `temp = temp.next` — what happens on the next iteration of the `for` loop after this, if `temp.next == null`?

Comment: The code in the method `remove` never removes `del`. it just sets the two nodes after `head` to `null`. I don't know much about this stuff, but I would think that you would find the node before `del` and the node after `del` and link them if they exist and then set `del` to `null`.

Comment: BTW shouldn't `remove()` also adjust the `size`? `size` is used at least two times in posted code - both will (eventually) fail if `size` is not correct. Actually, `remove()` will also fail if there is just one element on the list, that is, if `head.next == null` (I assume)

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/205233)

Comment: The `size` conversation brings in another important point: your class has two different pieces of state (the linked list, and the `size` var) that must always be in sync. Your class has two definitions of size: "the `int` var" and "how many times `.next` is non-null", and these need to always agree or else you'll have these sorts of bugs. Having that duplicated state isn't inherently bad, but it does mean you need to be very careful. Look up "invariants" for more info.